# Resize the subview when scrollview scroll in UIPangesture

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I have Create UIScrollview Programatically.I have added 5 View and each view have Imageview with image. I am doing zoom in/zoom out image using UIPanGesture i can  zoom in and zoom out image using PanGesture but when i scroll the scrollview then UIImageview not set its actual frame. i want to resize subview of scrollview when scrollview scroll.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Set your view controller a delegate of your scrollview:

```
scrollview.delegate = self;
```

Then, implement this delegate method in your viewcontroller:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
  // resize subview of scrollview here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set some object as the scrollview's delegate and then implement this method:

`-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)inScrollView`

Then you can do whatever you would like with the subviews whenever the scrollview scrolls (this includes automated scrolling, not just when the user scrolls).

Comment: i using this method but i can't resize subview of uiscrollview :(